# Show popup on double click of Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `gridview`  with few columns with `textboxes` in each column

**For Ex**

```
                -------------------------------------------
                | Row1        | Row2        |    Row3      |
                -------------------------------------------
                | TextBox1    | TextBox2    |    TextBox3  |
                -------------------------------------------
```

`HTML` :

```
    <Columns>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="openPopup"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="openPopup"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="openPopup"></asp:TextBox>
    </Columns>
```

When I `double click` on the `textbox` with different `ID`s I want to display a `bootstrap` modal popup

I have tried this but it is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.openPopup').dblclick(function () {
                $('#Div2').modal('show');
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the bootstrap `modal` to create the popup. Then bind to whichever `class` or `id` you wish inside the modal to display the passing data. Finally, inside the modal use `$(e.target).html()` to grab the double clicked data.

I strongly recommend, if you can, making use of `angularJS` or `backboneJS` to help you create a better UI experience on the front end.

```js
$('tr').on('dblclick', function(e) {

            $('#addModal').modal('show');
             $(".modal-body #dataToDisplay").text($(e.target).html());
  
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1 id="dataToDisplay"></h1>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>1st Table Row</td>
            <td>2nd Table Row</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which ever `textbox` I click I have to get the pupop, I cannot provide a specific `Id`

Comment: Will it be the same static popup for all text boxes or an individually customized one for each?

Comment: Yes, but the `modal popup` contains a textbox in the `modal-body`, where it has to display the text of the double clicked `textbox`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i is not working for me, the event is not even firing

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik Then you have something else in there blocking it. Its working just fine on the Snippet.

Comment: Is it something to do with the gridview